# How to set a header in wp_safe_remote_get()?

Tags: plugin-development, http-api

Previously I am using the below code. Now I need to change this code and replace   `file_get_contents()` with `wp_safe_remote_get()`. I need to know how to set  `'header' => "Accept: application/json"` in `wp_safe_remote_get()`:

```
$opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Content-Type:application/json",
            'header' => "Accept: application/json"
        )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file =   file_get_contents( 
    'http://xxxxxxxx.xxxx/xapix/xjson/xxxxx.php',
     false, 
     $context
);
```

I have tried to do this but not working

```
$args = array( 'timeout' => 30 , 'header' => "Accept: application/json");   
$file = wp_safe_remote_get('http://xxxxxxxx.xxxx/xapix/xjson/xxxxx.php', $args);
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: @MarkKaplun $args = array( 'timeout' => 30 , 'header' => "Accept: application/json"     );      $file = wp_safe_remote_get('http://xxxxxxxx.xxxx/xapix/xjson/xxxxx.php', $args);
I have tried this code but not working

Comment: so please edit your question to include that... and explain why do you think that the headers are not being send. Also it might be useful to know your server enviroment, do you have curl enabled or some other way in which http requests are being handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$args = array( 'headers' => array("Accept" => "application/json"));
$file = wp_safe_remote_get('http://xxxxxxxx.xxxx/xapix/xjson/xxxxx.php', $args);
```

headers is an array. Not a string .